# Loop over a list of other resources in terraform?

Tags: terraform, attributes, resources

For example, lets say I define a couple resources this way (in `.tf` format):

```
resource resource_type X {
    name = "X"
}

resource resource_type Y {
    name = "Y"
}
...
```

Now lets say later on I want to create new resources that will each correspond to one of the previously created resources (X,Y, ...) Is there a way to create a list that holds the previously created resource and then loop over that list like:

```
variable "list_of_previously_created_resources" {
    type = list(resource)
    default = [resource_type.X, resource_type.Y, ...]
}

# Now create corresponding resources:
resource type_Dependent d {
    for_each = var.list_of_previously_created_resource
    some_attribute = each.value.name
    depends_on = [each.value]
}
```

The syntax above of course does not work, but I tried my best to give the pseudo code for what I would like to do. Importantly, I don't necessarily want to loop over every resource of the type `"resource_type"` just those that I manually define in the list variable.

I don't see anything in the docs that describes the best way to do this, so here I am.

Comment: The question needs to contain concrete code to provide a definitive answer. While this is completely possible in theory, it may not be possible for your specific situation for some reason, and therefore we need to see the actual example of what you are attempting to achieve.

Comment: @MattSchuchard In theory, what syntax am I looking for? Can you direct me to the related documentation? Lets just say I need to do this abstractly (ie. I do of course have a specific use case, but may have others in the future that use a different provider/different resources in that provider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **can't declare dynamic variables**. But you can use `local` instead:

```
locals {
  list_of_previously_created_resources = [resource_type.X, resource_type.Y]
}

resource type_Dependent d {
    for_each = {for idx, val in local.list_of_previously_created_resource: idx => val}
    some_attribute = each.value.name
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the only thing that worked for me. I first tried `for_each = toset(local.list_of_previously_created_resources)` cause it looked easier, but then I got this error:

The "for_each" set includes values derived from resource attributes that
cannot be determined until apply, and so Terraform cannot determine the
full set of keys that will identify the instances of this resource.

When working with unknown values in for_each, it's better to use a map
value where the keys are defined statically in your configuration and where
only the values contain apply-time results.

Comment: In my case, the `toset` function works to convert a `local` to sth `for_each` can work with.